# How to configure AWS API Gateway without authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How do you setup and access an AWS API Gateway without an authorizer?

I've created an API Gateway that I want to be publicly accessible. It will be used to perform it's own authorization. But when I try to access its invocation URL, it returns the error response:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

I assume this is because the GET method for my gateway has Authorization=None. However, I don't want to use either AWS's lambda or cognito authorizers.

How do I change that to not require any built-in authorizer?

Comment: By default there is no authorizer in force. The message may have other reasons such as invalid hostname or host header, invalid api gw configuration (calling lambda, http endpoint,..). To resolve you would need to provide more information - e. g. deploy the api gw using the cloudformation, CDK or SAM and provide the script

Comment: @gusto2 I created a Lambda function [following this AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-3/) and then setup the API Gateway for it following the steps in this [Amazon tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-4/). I've deployed it. The only step I didn't follow was to set a Cognito authorizer. So I can only assume some type of authorizer is required and if none is set, than this is the error you're given.

Comment: It still doesn't say what you did or did not do. Maybe you could deploy a solution that is working (e.g. from the [examples](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/7ba1b0933324d4fa041c586056f2492647297479/examples/2016-10-31/api_backend/template.yaml) ) and compare the configuration.

Comment: @gusto2 I setup an API Gateway following their exact steps, and it works perfectly when I used a Cognito authorizer. If I change it to not use any authorizer, and make no other change, than it doesn't work. If I compare my working and non-working examples, the only difference is the lack of an authorizer. So it definitely seems to require an authorizer.

Comment: I have multiple deployments in prod and I'm definitely not using any authorizer as by default settings , so you have configured something that is not default

Comment: @gusto2 I followed their guides, and I've double checked everything. I also have multiple deployments in production. Telling me I missed something is not helpful. Even if you're right, that doesn't give me any actionable item. What other setting would require an authentication token even without an authenticator set?